# Do I need to free a managed BSTR used as a function parameter

Tags: c#, com

If I have managed COM interface called from unmanaged code, am I responsible for freeing up the memory after use or will it be handled by garbage collection?

```
 public void WriteOutFile([In] [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] String data)
 {
      File.WriteAllText(fileName, data);
      //do I need the line below??
      Marshal.FreeBSTR(data);
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not free the string because the caller can potentially reuse the data passed and if you free it is possible to have a fault. The reason is that `FreeBSTR` does not use any reference count mechanism and simply call [SysFreeString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f230ee3-5f6e-4cb9-a910-9c90b754dcd3%28VS.85%29), that by the way assumes that the string is allocated with one of the function `Sys(Re)Alloc...`, circumstance you are not aware of in the managed code.
The example [shown here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xda6xzx7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is interesting, imagin the *unmanaged* code calling you is this one ( from the link before ):

```
// shows using the Win32 function 
// to allocate memory for the string: 
BSTR bstrStatus = ::SysAllocString(L"Some text");
if (bstrStatus != NULL)
{
   pBrowser->put_StatusText(bstrStatus);
   // Free the string:
   ::SysFreeString(bstrStatus);
}
```

and you have imlemented `put_StatusText(...)` in your managed code we are reproducing your situation. As you can see is the caller responsible on allocating/deallocating the parameter string, **outside** the callee.

Answer (score 4):

Marshalling involves copying the data from unmanaged memory to managed memory. You don not need to free the `string` instance because it's a managed object. But if you allocate memory in the native code before the callback call, you need to free the memory in the native code after the callback call.